# Java Help User Input To Break While Loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I just made a simple math tutor game but I can't seem to figure out how to break it with a user input. This is what I got so far any help is appreciated.  I now know about comparing strings using .equals but i keep getting errors.

> "The method nextString() is undefined for the type Scanner"

and

"Exception in thread "main" InputMismatchException
    at throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at next(Unknown Source)
    at nextDouble(Unknown Source)".

Here is my code:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class HomeWork{

  public static void main(String[] args)  {

   while (true) 
{ 


    Scanner console =new Scanner(System.in);  


    double correctAnswer;

    double userResponse;

    String SecondResponse;

    String end = "stop";

    int n1 = (int)(10 * Math.random() + 1);

    int n2 = (int)(10 * Math.random() + 1);


    int operator = (int) (4 * Math.random() + 1);

    if  (operator == 1){              

        correctAnswer = n1 + n2;

        System.out.println("What is " + n1 +    " + "    + n2  + " ?");
 } else if ( operator == 2){      

        correctAnswer = n1 - n2;

        System.out.println("What is " + n1 +    " - "   + n2 + " ?");

    }  else if ( operator == 3) {  

    correctAnswer = n1 * n2;

        System.out.println("What is " + n1 +    " * "   + n2 + " ?");

    }   else {   

         correctAnswer = n1 / n2;

        System.out.println("What is " + n1 +    " / "   + n2 + " ?");

    }                    





    userResponse = console.nextDouble();





    if (userResponse == correctAnswer){
        System.out.println("You got the correct answer!");
        } else {

            System.out.println("Sorry but the correct answer is:" + correctAnswer);



        }

    SecondResponse = console.nextString();

    if(end.equals(SecondResponse)) 
        System.out.println("End of Program");
        break; 

    }  
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Many problems:

Your very last if... Is missing { braces }!

Because of that your break statement lives in the wrong place, as only that print statement is affected by the if condition.

Then: scanner has in deed no method nextString(). There is only next() for strings!

Don't make assumptions about what methods exist in a class. Consult the javadoc instead, especially when the compiler already gives you a hint that your assumption is not rooted in reality.

Comment: Youuuuu are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

> but i keep getting an error. "The method nextString() is undefined for
>   the type Scanner"

change this:

```
SecondResponse = console.nextString();
```

to this:

```
SecondResponse = console.next();
```

Also, make sure you open and close the braces properly:

```
if(end.equals(SecondResponse)) {
     System.out.println("End of Program");
     break; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you you are a life saver!